# TinyMCE editor in WordPress is not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've encountered this problem yesterday when I uploaded files to my testing website. Website is running on WordPress version 4.2.2. and I'm using my own theme which I've been developing for one client.

Now the problem is that the TinyMCE editor in WordPress started acting weird.

Here is the picture of my local deployment of the site:

[image: local deployment]

On local it works just fine. No problems or anything.

Here is the picture of my online deployment:

[image: online deployment]

As you can see there is a problem with it. The Text and Visual buttons are not rendered correctly and they've switched places.

When I click on Visual I get nothing in the editing area and on Text there is only one small part of the post's content.

Now I've tried almost everything I know to solve this problem. Here is the list of what I have tried so far:

- Uploaded another theme and tried switching to that theme to check if the problem is in the theme. No luck. Problem remains.
- I've tried disabling all parts in my theme to check if that will solve the problem. Still no luck.
- Today I've deleted the live database and whole wordpress folder on my web server and uploaded everything again. The problem still remains.

I have no clue what caused this problem at all. I have only one plugin and that is Contact Form 7 and I tried disabling it. Problem is still there. Another thing I'm using is Option Tree in my theme and set up to work in theme mode. I've tried disabling Option Tree as well, but no luck, problem remains.

Debug log isn't showing anything. Everything seems to work fine.

I've got something from chrome dev tools as you can see up in the second screenshot.

Whenever I switch between Text and Visual it throws one error in console. This problem is the same on Posts, Pages and Custom Post Type page.

Comment: You manually worked with the js or removed the wanted js files ?

Comment: Nope, haven't done anything with js files. I even got a fresh copy of wordpress and replaced everything but it remained the same.

Comment: Installed the ckeditor fresh too ?

Comment: I hope so. First, I've installed a whole new copy of WP. Then I tried copying only tinymce folder in wp-includes. After that I've tried copying the whole wp-includes folder and overwriting it. No help.

Comment: No, You should copy the plugin contents. You shall either install from local or install it via url

Comment: Can you tell me the path to that folder?